# Trying to retrieve only email id from a bounced email (gmail) and print it on screen

Tags: java

You all know how a postman email looks like
[image]

I am getting this as string from another class, kind of a response. from this string, I just want the email address mentioned, which is also in string format, so validations don't apply, I tried regex (entertaining my stupidity). I cant take index, bacause we have gmail now, but in production client can access any email right. Whats your solution. i just want the email address.

Answer (score 1):

You either match the e-mail with regex or extract the e-mail from the string by using `String.replace()` and `String.split()` methods:

```
 //remove leading text
 message = message.replace("Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:", "");

 //remove and trim newlines
 message = message.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "").trim();

 //the first part of split message will be the email address
 String emailAddress = message.split()[0];
```